# Trying to time jQuery each()

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to time a simple jQuery animation so that it triggers one by one on a set of HTML elements, and delays before moving on to the next set of elements. Using jQuery each() has not gotten me very far yet, as each() runs through the "item" variables instantly. Is there a way to time this so that it delays before moving on to the next "item" variable?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var slideShow = $(".intro-inner");
        if (slideShow) {
        var item = slideShow.find(".item");
        var headLine = item.find("h1");
        var para = item.find("p");
        item.each(function () { 
            if (headLine && para) {
                headLine.css({"opacity": "0", "left" : "-1.25em" });
                para.css({"opacity": "0", "left" : "-12.500em" });
                setTimeout(function() {
                    headLine.animate({"opacity": "1", "left" : "0"}, 4000);
                    para.animate({"opacity": "1", "left" : "0"}, 4000);
                }, 1000); 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `setTimeout` is missing the time..

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(callYouFunction(), time interval in miliseconds)
```

Comment: You'll need to set a global variable, to store the reference to which element is to be animated each time.

Answer (score 0):

`.each()` will pass [the index and the element](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to its callback function. You may be able to use this.

For instance, multiply the (zero-based) index by the number of seconds you're passing to `setTimeout` to animate each one a second after the one before it:

```
    item.each(function (i,el) { 
        if (headLine && para) {
            headLine.css({"opacity": "0", "left" : "-1.25em" });
            para.css({"opacity": "0", "left" : "-12.500em" });
            setTimeout(function() {
                headLine.animate({"opacity": "1", "left" : "0"}, 4000);
                para.animate({"opacity": "1", "left" : "0"}, 4000);
            }, i*1000); 
        }
    });
```